# React something is wrong with router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react redux and building my first web app.

So I created Router and added the specific pages:

```
   <Switch>
                <Route path="/">
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/Info/:id/:name/:type">
                    <Info />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
```

When I have `path="/"` and `path="/Info/:id/:name/:type"`, it does not work. But when I have something like 
 `path="/Home"`, `path="/Info/:id/:name/:type"`, it works very well. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: by not working, you mean you cannot navigate to the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by the nature of it, route is matched with the first path.
what you should do is use 'exact' in  your first path.

```
 <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Info/:id/:name/:type">
                <Info />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
```

Comment: hey @Abhishek.. `Switch` and `exact` are basically alternatives to each other. They don't actually need to work together in this case. even though it would work

Answer (score 1):

Pass 'exact' as a prop:

```
<Route path="/" exact><Home /></Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like i always remind my students.. `<Switch />` and `exact` are basically alternatives for each other..

If you have more than 2 or 3 routes.. go for `<Switch/>`. `exact` prop is only good enough for one time use only.

I have 2 answers for you.

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
</Route>
<Route path="/Info/:id/:name/:type">
    <Info />
</Route>
```

Just change the order of routes.. because Switch only takes the first match.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/Info/:id/:name/:type">
        <Info />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
        <Home />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```